# Powershell hangs on error

Tags: powershell

I just upgraded from Powershell 3.0 to 4.0 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=40855)

If I now run Powershell and enter a garbage command (e.g. Blah), Powershell will display an error and freeze. It does not go back to a prompt, and I'm not able to open another Powershell console until I kill the errant one.

[image]

I've run with `-noprofile` to rule out any funnies with modules.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Running on Windows 7 Professional SP1

**Edit:** Powershell ISE works fine, although it too can't be launched if I have a 'hung' PowerShell console still open.

Comment: Is anything returned when you run: $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction

Comment: @Windos. Nothing returned, and the console is still live

Comment: Does [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) with a filter for powershell.exe show what resources it's using? Can you show the [PSStackTrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751/can-i-get-detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell)?

Comment: @lloyd: There we go! ProcMon showed a particular module being loaded (well, attempting to load). If I remove that module, it all works as expected. If you repost as an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @HisRoyalRedness What was the module?

Comment: @DavidPostill: It was a custom one that I had written (convert a raw binary file to IntelHex file). I'm still not sure what the problem was. It was working fine up until I updated to PS 4.0. I confirmed that the module dll had been compiled against the correct .Net version and double-checked the PS module files. In the end, I recreated the module and script file from scratch, and it's now working again, with the original dll. I would still like to try figure out what went wrong when I have some free time if I can.